# How do I read the value of the Spring datasource URL regardless of where it is specified?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

In the Spring Boot documentation, it states that values provided on the command line that begin with `--` are converted to system properties.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.19.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-command-line-args

> By default SpringApplication will convert any command line option arguments (starting with ‘--’, e.g. --server.port=9000) to a property and add it to the Spring Environment.

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.arguments="-task report:weekly,--spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://xx.xx.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:3306/xx"
```

I've found that not to be true. I tried to print the datasource value and all three return `null`.

```
    System.out.println(System.getenv("SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL"));
    System.out.println(System.getProperty("spring.datasource.url"));
    System.exit(1);
```

> null
>   null
>   null

How do I get the value of the datasource, specifically the host, regardless of whether the datasource is provided in a property file, on the command line, or via an environment variable?

Comment: Have you tried adding a `@Value`-annotated field to a Spring bean?

Comment: Read again... It will be converted to a property NOT a system property! So trying to get them through `System.getProperty` won't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a class [`org.springframework.core.env.Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) which is Spring's abstraction over all properties received from different sources, by default including [`systemProperties`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html#getSystemProperties--) and [`systemEnvironment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/AbstractEnvironment.html#getSystemEnvironment--).

In order to get a property, inject the `Enviroment` and call [`Enviroment#getProperty`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/PropertyResolver.html#getProperty-java.lang.String-):

```
var property = environment.getProperty("spring.datasource.url");
```